# Add Authorization Bearer token for Sardine WebDav

Tags: java, webdav, sardine

I am researching Sardine Java library for WebDav access.
On the [User Guide](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/wiki/UsageGuide) page there is Authorization section, but uses only credentials type of authorization.

The WebDav server which I am trying to access supports `Bearer Token` authorization.

Is it possible to configure Sardine to include `Authorization` header in the requests, so I can use token instead of username/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I used this constructor `public SardineImpl(String bearerAuth)` and it worked fine